# Draw a specific "no-formula" graph in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

How can I draw something like this picture in `tikz`? This is what I wanna draw.

[image]

Comment: See [my recent answer here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/567902/4778), for example, but you can find a ton on the site, as [this research for "random plot"](https://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=random+plot) shows.

Comment: @Alenanno actually I dindn't meant definitely random I just didn't know how should I call that.could you help me draw diagram I mentioned please?I couldn't understand how change points to what I want

Comment: I see. Can you specify what you meant by random then? Otherwise I'm not sure I understand the question.

Comment: @Alenanno I meant a graph without specific equation like picture above

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Best way to draw graphs of functions for students](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/567888/best-way-to-draw-graphs-of-functions-for-students)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
    
\begin{tikzpicture} 
\begin{axis}[axis lines*=middle, xtick=\empty, ytick=\empty]    
\addplot [smooth,tension=0.9] coordinates {(1,5)(1.5,3)(3.5,2)(5,-4)(6,4)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

You can insert some random points and get a plot joining all of them

Comment: yes thank you soooo much. but is there any way to specify Concave or Convex? because the last part of diagram is wrong

Comment: You just need to add another point after (6,4) to change the curvature. For example (7,5)

Comment: thanks for your great help and short code!

Comment: You're welcome¡ I recommend you to play with ```tension```. P.D I think (7,6) at the end of coordinates is a better option for your desired result than (7,5)

Answer (score 2):

Pure TikZ variant, drawing with `controls` :

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                intersections}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[%smooth,scale=0.8
         > = Straight Barb,
dot/.style = {circle, draw, thick, fill=blue, inner sep=2pt,
              label={[fill=white, inner sep=1pt, font=\small]60:#1},
              node contents={},}
                        ]
% axis
\draw[->] (-1,0) -- (6,0) node[below left] {$x$};
\draw[->] (0,-3) -- (0,5) node[below left] {$y$};
% some function
\draw[red, very thick, name path=A]
        (0.5,4) .. controls + (0,-1) and + (-1,0) .. (1.5, 2)
                .. controls + (1,0) and + (-0.5,1.5) .. (3,0)
                .. controls + (0.5,-1.5) and + (-0.5,1) .. (4,-2.5)
                .. controls + (1,-1.5) and + (-1,-2) .. (6,3);
% determine coordinates by intersections
\foreach \x in {1,2}
{
    \path[name path=B\x]   (\x,0) -- ++ (0,5);
    \draw[densely dashed, 
          name intersections={of=A and B\x,by={B\x}}] 
          (B\x) -- (\x,-1pt) node[below, font=\footnotesize] {\x};
}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thank you it really helped me